# Username and password integrating application with Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm having trouble with Microsoft Teams in the sense that I does not recognise my username and password that I enter in my application.  I'm able to get my application to display inside the Teams page, but when I capture my username and password, Teams re-display the login screen.  I'm using asp.net core identity framework to authenticate my users.

When I add [anounamous] tags to my controllers, it's possible to navigate to those pages.  But anything that is not decorated with [announoumus] will force me back to the login screen and then Teams does not recognise the login details.

It is as if it does not know how to read the information in the cookie.

I'm able to load the manifest.json file without any issues, then select the page to display on the Team Tab.   But when I try to navigate to a "restricted" page that requires my user to be logged in, Teams display my login page.

Below is a link to the Manifest file if anyone is able to help:  dropbox.com/s/wxw3xtk1458blbu/Ezymapps.zip?dl=0

Comment: Could you please provide your manifest, so we can check this?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Here is a link to the file.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxw3xtk1458blbu/Ezymapps.zip?dl=0

Comment: Please check [Authentication flow for tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab)